# For diffeomorphism $f$, if $X$ and $f(X)$ are both Gaussian, then $f$ is affine

Tags: pr.probability, optimal-transportation

I am trying to prove the following.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a diffeomorphism. If $X$ and
> $f(X)$  are both $n$ -dimensional Gaussian variables, then $f$ is
> affine. That is, there exists a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)=Ax+b$.

**Context**

The problem I am trying to solve is the following optimal transport problem in the Monge setting:

> Let $\mu_0$ be the probability distribution of $n$-dimensional
> Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and the covariance matrix
> $\Sigma_0$. Define $\mu_1$ similarly with mean $0$ and the covariance
> matrix $\Sigma_1$.
>
> Find the diffeomorphism $\eta$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that minimizes
>
> $\displaystyle \begin{equation}  J(\eta)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}d(x,\eta(x))^2d\mu_0\end{equation}\tag*{}$
>
> under the constraint $\eta_*\mu_0=\mu_1$, where $\eta _*\mu_0$ is [the
> push-forward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) and
> $d(x,y)$ is the Euclidean distance.

I have already solved this problem in the case $\eta$ is linear, so I figured I should reduce this problem into a linear one.

The condition $\eta_*\mu_0=\mu_1$ is equivalent to $\mu_0(\eta^{-1}(A))=\mu_1(A)$ for any measurable $A$. In probabilistic notation, we have $P(\eta(X)\in A)=P(Y\in A)$ where $X\sim N(0,\Sigma_0),Y\sim N(0,\Sigma_1)$. This implies $\eta(X)$, and $Y$ have the same distribution. Therefore, both $X$ and $\eta(X)$ are Gaussian (with zero mean).

If $n=1$, then we can easily prove that the diffeomorphism that makes $X$ and $f(X)$ both Gaussian are affine, as we can see here: [Gaussian-to-gaussian transformations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/393009/295387).

In higher dimensions, the paper [Transformations preserving normality and Wishart-ness](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X86900813?ref=cra_js_challenge&fr=RR-1) seems to suggest that we have that $f$ is affine for closely related, general case. (The paper asserts a bijective bimeasurable function that preserves normality for a fixed mean, and any covariance matrix is affine)

**My Attempt**
We can apply some affine transformation $L$ so that $L\circ f(X)$ has the same distribution as $X$. Thus without loss of generality, we can assume $X$ and $f(X)$ have the same distribution. For simplicity, I will assume $\Sigma_0=\Sigma_1=I$(the identity matrix).

My first guess was that for $f(X)=(Y_1,\cdots, Y_n)$, each $Y_1,\cdots Y_n$ should not depend on more than one $X_i$. This is wrong since $f(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2)$ has the distribution $N(0,I)$ and $f$ is diffeomorphism.

I had a few more failed attempts, but I will omit them to make this post not too long.

Comment: I would imagine that $f$ could rotate the points at distance $r$ from the origin by an angle that depends on $r$, and that would take something rotation invariant, like a Gaussian, to itself. But I don't know any probability theory.

Comment: @BenMcKay Hmm, I feel like the Jacobian could be complicated in that case which makes the pdf of f(X) not Gaussian, since the pdf of f(X) can be found by multiplying the pdf of X and the Jacobian of $f^{-1}$. It also feels contradictory to the paper I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Ben McKay's idea stated in the comment above is a natural one for a counterexample.

Indeed, for $(x,y)\in\R^2$, let
$$f(x,y):=f((x,y)):=
\left(x \cos \left(r^2\right)-y \sin \left(r^2\right),\ 
x \sin \left(r^2\right)+y \cos
   \left(r^2\right)\right),$$
where $r^2:=x^2+y^2$.
The transformation $f$ is bijective, with
$$f^{-1}((x,y))=
\left(x \cos \left(r^2\right)+y \sin \left(r^2\right),\ 
-x\sin \left(r^2\right)+y \cos
   \left(r^2\right)\right)$$
for all $(x,y)\in\R^2$.
Note also that
$$|f^{-1}((x,y))|^2=r^2 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all $(x,y)\in\R^2$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Also,
$$\text{the Jacobian determinant of $f$ is $1\ne0$ everywhere on $\R^2$.} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
So, $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Also, it follows from \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, and the formula for the change of variables under the (double) integral sign that $f(X)$ is a standard normal random vector in $\R^2$ provided that $X$ is a standard normal random vector in $\R^2$.

However, it is clear that the transformation $f$ is not affine. (For instance, the partial derivative of the first coordinate of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ equals $1$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $-1$ at $(x,y)=(0,\sqrt\pi)$.)

Comment: Nice example. The link « Ben McKay's idea » does not work.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan : Thank you for your comment. Strangely enough, the link almost works for me if I want to open it in a new tab or a new window (pointing actually to another comment), but not at all in the same tab. I don't know how to fix this. :-(

Comment: A solution could be to copy the URL address.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan : I have now tried this, the way I understood you. The result is the same as before. If you know how to fix this, please feel free to edit the answer accordingly.